# When we measure our distance from a very distant astrophysical object image do we input its past location and our present location?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, space-expansion, redshift

When we measure our distance from a very distant astrophysical object do we input its past location and our present location? Please take a look on the picture where our past location is A1 and the distant object past location B1, and A2 and B2 are respective present locations.So do we actually measure A2B1 as the distance for example for GN-z11(measuring redshift)?
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measures_(cosmology) has a good summary of the various ways to express cosmological distances. But mostly, cosmologists just use redshift, since it's directly measurable & unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

There are many 'distance measures' used in cosmology, it gets very complicated.  A good review is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9905116) 'Distance Measures in Cosmology', by D.Hogg

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let's say you look at a planet about 13 light years away. You will see what the planet looked 13 years ago. But you will also see where the object was 13 years ago.